# CSS Animation Keyframes not working on Iphone/Ipad

Tags: css, animation, safari, keyframe

I have made a keyframe animation with words shifting in the end of the sentence. It works in Chrome, but doesn't work in Safari.

What am I doing wrong?

This is the CSS code:

```
.aboutvision span:before {
content: '';
animation: about-vision 8s infinite;
color: #faf9f4;
text-decoration: underline;
display: inline-block;
}

@keyframes about-vision {
    0%{
        content: 'GROW';
    }
    
    25%{
        content: 'THRIVE';
    }   
    
    50%{
        content: 'UNFOLD';
    }   
    
    75%{
        content: 'EVOLVE';
    }
    
    100%{
        content: 'GROW';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `content` property is no animatable according to the CSS spec. Here is [a list of properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties) that can be animated. Chrome does support it nonetheless since 2020. (See also this [CSS-Tricks article](https://css-tricks.com/animating-the-content-property/) on the issue)

To make this work across all browsers you could use JavaScript or make a different element for each `content` value and animate their display or opacity values individually.